# Exception while Merging the Conflict in C# code - VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am getting the attached error message whenever I try to Merge a Conflict in my C# code in VS2015. Please let me know the reason.

[image]

Following is the error in the ActivityLog.xml

[image]

Comment: The reason is that there was a null argument provided in `ExtensionsManager.OnTextViewCreated`.

Comment: Oh, Where to update it?

Comment: It's a bug somewhere in ExtensionsManager. File a bug report with MS and provide them the details regarding how to reproduce it, so they can fix it in an update.